# Returning Iterator instead of Collection

Tags: java, collections, iterator, synchronize, iterable

Is there any advantage or where returning a iterator is more desirable that a collection in methods for data access layer?

I´ve seen it somewhere, and don´t remember why.

P.S: Maybe it has to do with realtime fetching of some data while is not complete

Comment: Not sure how you would use an iterator to do 'runtime-fetching'. Iterators are objects that can iterate over collections, if the data isn't already in the collection the iterator does not see it.

Comment: Something like this link I´ve found (but its not update nor talks about best practices) http://www.techrepublic.com/article/deciding-between-iterators-and-lists-for-returned-values-in-java/1046675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A JDBC `ResultSet` basically works like that, though it's a different and more complex interface. And yes, the reason for that is that it allows processing huge datasets without first fetching them entirely into memory.

Also, some other languages (C++ and Python, I belive) idiomatically use iterators as data items to be passed around. In Java, this is generally not done and should be avoided (unless there is a compelling reason) because Java's iterators lack some important functionality that makes them much less useful than a Collection - namely, you cannot copy them or reset their position.

Answer (score 2):

The Iterator has a much simpler interface than the Collection, and should be easier to implement a custom wrapper that does things the way you want them.

As you mentioned, you can implement it such that the next() method blocks until the data is available. Also, you can choose to not implement the remove() operation and thus not allow the caller to alter the underlying collection.